# Mat Dialog Container

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dialog

My Dialog content doesn't seem to fit the dialog container as i want it too. it still shows spaces all around the dialog content. it doesn't closely fit the container. can anyone help me out on changing the dialog container errors.

```
<div class="dialog-content-wrapper"></div>
    <mat-toolbar matDialogTitle class="mat-accent m-0">
      <mat-toolbar-row fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
        <span class="title dialog-title">Info</span>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="matDialogRef.close()" aria-label="Close dialog">
          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
<div mat-dialog-content class="p-24 m-0"></div>
```

Does anybody know how to fix it so that it should closely and nicely fit the container & the scroll bar should be closer to the content.[image: this is how the image of the dialog looks like]

Comment: Maybe a css issue?